# Update picker values on button click swift 1.2

Tags: ios, swift

I have a working picker view with following lines of code

```
@IBOutlet var myPicker: UIPickerView!

var colors: [String] = ["red","green","blue"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()     

        myPicker = UIPickerView()
        myPicker.dataSource = self
        myPicker.delegate = self
}

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return colors.count
    }

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
        return colors[row] as! String
    }
```

i have a button when i click i want to remove all the old values (i'e red, green and blue) and update with the new values (yellow, black)

```
func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton!) {
        var btn:UIButton = sender;
        colors = ["yellow", "black”]
        myPicker.reloadAllComponents()
}
```

but unfortunately the above code is not working, i'm a newbie in swift and dont know how to implement this, can someone please help me on this?

Comment: Does something not work when you implement it the way you show?

Comment: yes it does not update the values

Comment: Your code seems to be valid. Make sure than `buttonClicked` is called when your button is clicked.

Comment: Yes, the buttonClicked is called but it is not updating the values :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have two picker views. The source of the issue is these lines:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    myPicker = UIPickerView() // this is the problem
    myPicker.dataSource = self
    myPicker.delegate = self
}
```

You are setting `myPicker` to a completely new and different UIPickerView which you are creating in that line (the one that I've marked with a comment). This is *not* the picker view that is already in your interface (the one you set up in the storyboard). And you never place *this* one into the interface. Thus:

- The picker view in the interface is left untouched by all your code; the one in the interface never gets a data source, never gets a delegate, and never reloads anything.
- The picker view you *create* in these lines does all those things, but it is not in the interface so you don't see it do anything.